# laravel - sortBy() not working properly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have collection with subcollections like:

```
+
+--- name: 1a8 Lorem Ipsum
+
+--- name: 1a2 Lorem Ipsum
+
+--- name: 1a10 Lorem Ipsum
```

and now I want to sort it by this name:

```
$collection->sortBy('name')
```

It should be:

```
1a2 Lorem Ipsum
1a8 Lorem Ipsum
1a10 Lorem Ipsum
```

but I'm getting:

```
1a10 Lorem Ipsum
1a2 Lorem Ipsum
1a8 Lorem Ipsum
```

Why? I have tried too with `$collection->sortBy('name', SORT_NATURAL, false)` but it's same effect.

Comment: because its looked at like a string...

Comment: The sorting looks fine, the `name` field contains strings and is sorted in this way.

Comment: Yea, but the string starts with a number, which might causes it to be turned into an integer, 1.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36716875/2943403

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What might be happening is that because your values are starting with an integer, is that they are turned into an integer value. That means anything after the first non-numeric character is discared. In your case you're left with 3 `1`'s

You might want to use a custom sorting callback that implements [strnatcmp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strnatcmp.php)

```
$collection->sort(function($a, $b) {
   // using 3 = for type and value comparisan.
   if($a->name === $b->name) {
      return 0;
   };
   return strnatcmp($a->name, $b->name);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is already in the answer by @Tschallacka. if you want an explanation of why is this happening let me explain.

The function `sortBy` is receiving a `string`. String sorting is analyzed column by column (char position by char position). Integer or numeric type sorting, is analyzed by value.

So if we try to sort: `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13...` as string we would get something like: `1,10,11,..2,20,21.`

Since you are mixing both, you need a solution like the one given already.