# Laravel Eloquent Order By Alphanumeric value

Tags: php, laravel, web-deployment, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

I am using laravel 6.x, i have rows like this

```
Plot 4
Plot 5
Plot 2
Plot 4B
Plot 3
Shop 2
Shop 1
```

I want result like this

```
Plot 2
Plot 3
Plot 4
Plot 4B
Plot 5
Shop 1
Shop 2
```

Thanks

Comment: please post the code so we can try to help you fix it

Comment: This needs more details. Please describe the table, column type and any code you are using to display the data.

Comment: Show your `controller` where you have written the `method`.. For PHP you can use `natsort($array);`.

Comment: I have accounts table having column type varchar, `\App\Account::whereHas('parent', function($q){
            $q->where('title', 'Sales');
        })->with('item', 'journals', 'item.sales', 'item.sales.reminders', 'item.sales.user')
            ->orderByRaw('LENGTH(title)')
            ->orderBy('title')
            ->paginate(30);`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36716875/2943403

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Laravel you should look at their documentation for collections and their sort method.

Start with creating collections:
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#creating-collections

And then look at sorting:
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-sort

That should get you there. If you post details of your attempts so far we can help you get it working.

If you're using an eloquent model to get your data from a database then it will come as a collection already then you simply need to sort by the relevant key eg.

```
Model::all()->sortBy('column');
```